# Random number generator code problems

Tags: c, random

I am using a Dev C++ GCC complier on windows. I used this code for my random number generator which prints 10 random numbers comprised of 0s and 1s

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main()
{
    int i,n;
    int arr[50];
    //int z=0,o=0;
    //time_t t;

    printf("Enter the no of binary random nos you want");
    scanf("%d",&n);


    //initializes the random number generator
    srand(time(NULL));

    //print the random numbers
    printf("The random numbers are: ");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++);
    {
         arr[i]=rand()%2;
         printf("%d",arr[i]);

    }

    return (0);
}
```

However, it prints only one random number  at a time instead of 10. Any help in pointing out my mistake will be appreciated

Comment: Re-write `for(i=0;i<n;i++);
    {
         arr[i]=rand()%2;
         printf("%d",arr[i]);

    }` to print 10 numbers - limbed a `for(int n=0; n<10; n++)`

Comment: Start using a debugger. You'd have found out instantly.

Comment: Note that `rand` is often implemented as a linear congruential generator, LCGs have notoriously bad behavior in the last bit, and using `rand()%2` is picking the last bit...  You'd do better to pick off a bit from the middle, and even better to avoid `rand`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `;` in this line

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++);
```

As a result, what you think is the body of the loop is executed outside the loop

Always compile with warnings enabled, many compilers will warn you know about it.

Answer (score 0):

you are having one problem in your code

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++);
```

remove `;` at the end

use `for(i=0;i<n;i++)`

if you are using `for(i=0;i<n;i++);` it will loop from 0 to n and terminate at `;`
after that it will execute below line and print 1 random number.

By using `;` below code will not be the part of `for` loop.